# Show uniform stability of the system

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory, linear-control

the LTV system $\dot x(t)=A(t)x(t)$ is called uniformly stable if $\exists \gamma>0$ such that $\left\| {\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)} \right\| \leqslant \gamma $ for all $t\ge t_0$ where ${\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)}$ is the state transition matrix.

my question: say that I know that: $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\left\| {x\left( 0 \right)} \right\| \leqslant \delta$ $\rightarrow$ $\left\| {x\left( t \right)} \right\| \leqslant \varepsilon $ for all $t\ge t_0$, how could I show system is uniformly stable?

Comment: Use the transition matrix in the second statement, bound, conclude.

Comment: @KBS what you described will depend on $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ and hence the initial condition $x(0)$, whereas uniform stability definition should be independent of $x(0)$

Comment: You will have to use the quantifiers correctly.

Comment: @KBS would be great if you could write it down, I did try something but I was never convinced it is correct

Comment: As it is an exercise, it is customary that you write your attempts first and then you will get some help.

Comment: here is what I was thinking about:$\begin{gathered}
  \left\| {x\left( t \right)} \right\| = \left\| {\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)x\left( 0 \right)} \right\| \leqslant \left\| {\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)} \right\|\left\| {x\left( 0 \right)} \right\| \leqslant \left\| {\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)} \right\|\delta  \leqslant \varepsilon  \hfill \\
   \Rightarrow \left\| {\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)} \right\| \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon }{\delta } \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

Comment: Update your answer with that under some new paragraph. But the issue here is that it is $||x(t)||$ that is less than $\epsilon$, not $\left\| {\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)} \right\|\left\| {x\left( 0 \right)} \right\|$.

Comment: @KBS yes, you are right!! I wonder how to go around this !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition that $||x(t)||\le\dfrac{\epsilon}{\delta}||x(t_0)||$ for all $t\ge t_0$ is equivalent to the definition of uniform stability. Now, we have that

$$||x(t)||=||\Phi(t,t_0)x(t_0)||\le\dfrac{\epsilon}{\delta}||x(t_0)||,\ t\ge t_0.$$

Since, this is true for all $x(t_0)$, then this implies that $||\Phi(t,t_0)||\le\gamma:=\dfrac{\epsilon}{\delta}$ for all $t\ge t_0$.

Comment: how did you deduce the inequality $\left\| {x\left( t \right)} \right\| \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon }{\delta }\left\| {x\left( {{t_0}} \right)} \right\|$

Comment: This is equivalent to the definition of uniform stability. This is often used as the main definition, in fact.

Comment: could you pinpoint the source where the equivalence is indicated or it is obvious ?

Comment: @dazzmine This should be available in any textbook or lecture notes on the topic but this is also kind of immediate.

Comment: How could you deduce last statement from inequalities, is it trivial ?

Comment: @dazzmine It comes from the properties of induced-norms.

Comment: you mean by writing $\left\| {\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)x\left( 0 \right)} \right\| \leqslant \left\| {\Phi \left( {t,{t_0}} \right)} \right\|\left\| {x\left( t_0 \right)} \right\|$

Comment: but then how do you know the right handside is less than $\frac{\varepsilon }{\delta }\left\| {x\left( {{t_0}} \right)} \right\|$

Comment: No this is the sub-multiplicative property of the norm. I am talking about operator induced norm. You asked a question recently about that.

Comment: you mean we treat $\Phi$ as an operator, right?

Comment: even if we do so, I guess we end up with the inequality I wrote

Comment: Yes, but your sequence of arguments is not correct.

Comment: I know this might like I m asking too much, but would be great if you could show me that middle step before last argument :)

Comment: If for an operator $M:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $||Mx||\le \alpha||x||$ for some $\alpha>0$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then we have that $||M||\le\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help! I guess I need to work little bit more on my fundamentals!!